# Customizing the PRINT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 2 PRINT statements in my code that look like this:

```
DECLARE @Msg VARCHAR(300)= 'Delete Email addresses that have been in the table for more than 30 days.';
PRINT @Msg;

-- If the email address has been in the table for more than 30 days, it should be removed
DELETE
--SELECT *
FROM CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY_EMAILS
WHERE DATE_ADDED < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())


DECLARE @Msg1 VARCHAR(300)= 'Append data to the final table if it doesnt already exist.';
PRINT @Msg1;

-- Copy all records from the staging table where no existing email address exists in the final table
INSERT INTO CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY_EMAILS(ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME, CONTACT_EMAIL, DATE_ADDED)
SELECT 
A.ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME,
A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
A.CUSTOMER_FULL_NAME,
A.CONTACT_EMAIL,
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) as DATE_ADDED
FROM CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY A
LEFT JOIN CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY_EMAILS B
  ON A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
  AND A.CONTACT_EMAIL = B.CONTACT_EMAIL
WHERE B.DATE_ADDED IS NULL
  AND A.ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME NOT LIKE '%UNKNOWN%'
```

The output looks like this:

> Delete Email addresses that have been in the table for more than 30
> days.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)
> Append data to the final table if it doesnt already exist.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)

I've got a couple questions.  First, is there any way to integrate the number of records into the custom message and remove them from the automated message?  i.e.:

> Delete Email addresses that have been in the table for more than 30 days.  This step affected 0 row(s).
>
> Append data to the final table if it doesnt already exist.  This step affected 0 row(s).

Second, how do you get a custom print message to print an apostrophe?  I had to remove it from the word "doesnt" because I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Does @@ROWCOUNT already know, or do I need to define it?  I apologize, I used to be closer to an Intermediate user but I haven't touched it in about a year.

Comment: When wanting to include a single quote in a string literal you have to escape it with another single quote. So you string would be something like 'it doesn''t already'

Comment: @SeanLange - Thanks!  That was easier than expected.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn `NOCOUNT` to `ON`, meaning you don't get the `(0 row(s) affected)` messages and then `PRINT` *after* the statement completed and incorporate the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` into printed message:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE
FROM dbo.CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY_EMAILS
WHERE DATE_ADDED < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());

PRINT CONCAT(N'Delete Email addresses that have been in the table for more than 30 days. This step affected ', @@ROWCOUNT,N' row(s).');
```

Comment: "after the statement completed" in this case being **immediately** after, otherwise `@@ROWCOUNT` will not be correct

Comment: Had to actually set NOCOUNT to ON, but that was just a quick google to fix it.

Comment: Yep, sorry, brain was in reverse there, @JohnnyBones , it's already in holiday mode as it's a 4 day weekend here. Fixed.